# How to use global variable in python, in a threadsafe way

Tags: python, thread-safety, global-variables

I want to use a global variable, 
Init it once.
having a thread safe access.

Can someone share an example please?

Comment: Googled python variable scope. First link : http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/

Comment: What do you mean by thread safe?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx

Answer (score 7):

If you need read-only access and the value is initialized before threads are spawn, you don't need to worry about thread safety.

If that is not the case Python [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) library is probably what you need, more precisely locks. A really good read on the subject - http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm with quite a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a problem if you are using multiprocessing.Processes. In which case you should take a look at Managers and Queues in the multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 1):

The [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library is what you want:

```
import threading
mydata = threading.local()
mydata.x = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize it once, and if you initialize it on when module is loaded (that means: before it can be accessed from other threads), you will have no problems with thread safety at all. No synchronization is needed.

But if you mean a more complex scenario, you have to explain it further to get a reasonable code example.